# Run a batch process on Excel files and edit VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make the same amendments to the VBA code in numerous excel files. The files are stored in a nested directory structure, with each file residing in its own folder, e.g:

```
-> Main Folder
  -> Record No.
       Excel File
```

The VBA code on each file is password protected (with the same password).

Is it possible to create a macro in Excel that could perform this operation? Or is it beyond the scope of Excel and VBA.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice on the matter.

Noel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- on several excel files : use the FSO to get the names & folders of every file you need to amend
- unlock VBA : workbooks.Unprotect
- modify VBA : you can use the workbooks.VBProject.VBComponents object (modifying the code that is being runned may lead to crashes of course)

==> yes it is totally possible :-)